# Changing JSON format to have a proper key for hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I feel like I'm *almost* where I need to be here but I'm not quite sure how to change this and loop the JSON properly

Currently, by the snippet below, I'm accessing each element of the JSON one by one, but I want to change it so that it's accessing by pageID of the JSON. You can see in the JSON below there are 4 elements, but I want to treat them as two, grouped by pageID, so I would still be treating the different panel_type_id and content of each element.

WIth the snippet below it's loading Left 93 then Right 93, then repeats with Left new and Right New.

What I WANT to do, is make this so that on load it simultaneously shows Left 93 and Right 93 (both assigned to pageID 93) and then after a few seconds of the interval, it shows simultaneously Left New and Right New. Think of it like a slide change after a countdown. In this case there are two slides (pageID 93 and pageID 94, each with 2 elements of content). I wish I had a good websites or app example but I'm thinking of leaderboard-style apps where there are 5 slides assigned to a display and when the countdown timer ends it goes to the next slide and so on. It's getting the data, showing it all in the console but I just need to refactor either my JSON formatting or my looping here.

What can I do to fix this issue?

```js
let obj = [{
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "86",
    "panel_type_id": "2",
    "cont_id": "138",
    "contID": "138",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "3",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
{
    "pageID": "94",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "75",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "2",
    "cont_id": "141",
    "contID": "141",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft New<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
 {
    "pageID": "94",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "75",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "88",
    "panel_type_id": "3",
    "cont_id": "140",
    "contID": "140",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight New<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  }
];
let counter = 0;

var fullContent = document.getElementById('fullContent');
var leftContent = document.getElementById('leftContent');
var rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');

var fullColumn = document.getElementById('fullColumn');
var leftColumn = document.getElementById('leftColumn');
var rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightColumn');



setInterval(() => {
  const currentJSONobject = obj[counter];

  if (currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 1) {

    leftColumn.style.display = "none";
    rightColumn.style.display = "none";
    

    if (currentJSONobject.panel_type_id == 1) {

      fullContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content;
    }

    //If half page    
  } else if (currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 2) {

    fullColumn.style.display = "none";


    if (currentJSONobject.panel_type_id == 2) {

      leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content;

    } else if (currentJSONobject.panel_type_id == 3) {

      rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content;
    }
  }

  $('#middle').css('background-image', 'url(' + currentJSONobject.background_img + ')');

  counter += 1;
  if (counter === obj.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }

}, 2500)
//console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row middle">
  <!-- Full Page Divs -->
  <div class="col-lg-12" id="fullColumn">
    <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style="height: 100%; ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Full Page Divs -->

  <!-- Half Page Divs -->
  <div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn">

    <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 rightColumn">

    <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- End Half Page Divs -->
</div>
```